# Kendo DateTimePicker format HHmm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo datetimepicker control and when a user manually types in an incorrect format missing the colon in the time, the validation does not catch this and in the MVC controller, the models property has a null date/time.

My client side validation is able to parse 21/01/2015 1230 but by the time it reaches the model in the controller server side its null, as it cannot map and parse the datetime.

Some console.log output of the value input and kendo.parseDate's effort.
21/01/2015 0000
Wed Jan 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Here's my client-side validation below.
So how can I force the validation to work client-side?

```
$("#accidentForm").kendoValidator({
rules: {
            date: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=Accident.IncidentDate]")) {
                    console.log(input.val());
                    var d = kendo.parseDate(input.val());
                    console.log(d);
                    return d instanceof Date;
                }

                return true;
            }
        },
        messages: {
            customRuleDateTimePick: "Incident date time format incorrect."
        }
    });

    // attach a validator to the container and get a reference
    var validatable = $("#accidentForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        //validate the input elements and check if there are any errors
        if (validatable.validate() === false) {
            // get the errors and write them out to the "errors" html container
            var errors = validatable.errors();
            $(errors).each(function () {
                $("#errors").html(this);
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Ok I seem to have solved it I think by using the kendo.parseDate with a format option and culture.

Answer (score 0):

OK specifying a format and culture parameter on the kendo.parseDate seems to help and stops the post to the server until a valid date AND time is input.

```
$("#accidentForm").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
            date: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=Accident.IncidentDate]")) {
                    var d = kendo.parseDate(input.val(), ["dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"], 'en-GB');
                    return d instanceof Date;
                }

                return true;
            }
        },
        messages: {
            date: "Incident date time format incorrect."
        }
    });
```

Another alternative, simpler I think, was to extend the validator methods for date types.  This then picked up the MVC error message attributes, so I get to use the right resource.resx file rather than hard code my error text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            // Custom validation required for DateTimePicker, so use kendo.parseDate as it works better than jquery unobtrusive validation.
            return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseDate(value, ["dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"], 'en-GB') !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
```